# Create database table using c#.net with variable of table name

Tags: c#, sql, create-table

I tried so many things but I couldn't find a solution..

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string NewTable = TxtPanoNo.Text;


        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE" + NewTable + ""+ "(id tinyint,KullanilanAdet smallint,Tip nchar(20),Kod varchar(50),Ad varchar(50),Aciklama varchar(500),Favori bit)", bgl.baglanti()))
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Succeed");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }



    }
```

and the error is:

> incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: Apart from the simple syntax error which you could've spotted by inspecting the string, why do you want to create tables on demand? Shouldn't `PanoNo` simply be a column in the same table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no space between `CREATE TABLE` and the table-name. Instead use:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + NewTable + "(id tinyint, ... and so on
```